# Geometric/vector explanation of $\det(A)=0\iff$ unique solution doesn't exist to system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vectors, systems-of-equations

Currently, I am self-studying Multivariable Calculus. I have prior knowledge about Vectors, Matrices and System of Linear Equations. However, the linkages between the three are not explicitly covered by my prior education and curriculum. I reckon it is beneficial for me to build a correct understanding about these linkages.

I am not most familiar with the language of Mathematics. I apologize for any inaccuracies or intracies throughout my question in advance.

---

TL;DR: Explain the following geometrically / from "vector view":$$\begin{align}&\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ are linearly dependent}\\\impliedby&\overrightarrow{d}\text{ cannot be expressed in any linear combination of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\end{align}$$

---

Suppose there is a system of linear equations in the forms $$x\overrightarrow{a}+y\overrightarrow{b}+z\overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{d}$$

and $$\mathbf{A}\overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{d}$$

From my understanding, solving this system of linear equations is conceptually equivalent to:

1. in a "vector view", expressing $\overrightarrow{d}$ in terms of linear combination(s) of $\overrightarrow{a}$, $\overrightarrow{b}$ and $\overrightarrow{c}$;
2. in a "matrix view", solving $\overrightarrow{x}=\mathbf{A}\overrightarrow{d}$.

**My goal is to understand "$\det(\mathbf{A}^{-1})=0\iff\text{unique solution doesn't exist}$" from the "vector view".**

I believe there is a logical explanation to my question: $$\begin{align}&\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ are linearly dependent}\\\iff&\det\mathbf{A}=0\\\iff&\text{unique solution doesn't exist}\\\iff&\text{no solution or infinitely many solutions}\\\iff&\overrightarrow{d}\text{ cannot be expressed in any linear combination of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\\&\text{ or there exist infinitely many linear combinations of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ expressing }\overrightarrow{d}\end{align}$$

To put it simply, the logical explanation is $$\begin{align}&\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ are linearly dependent}\\\iff&\overrightarrow{d}\text{ cannot be expressed in any linear combination of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\\&\text{ or there exist infinitely many linear combinations of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ expressing }\overrightarrow{d}\end{align}$$

From the definition of basis vectors, I know that $$\begin{align}&\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ are linearly independent}\\\iff&\overrightarrow{d}\text{ can be expressed in }\mathbf{unique }\text{ linear combination of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\end{align}$$

and I understand that the negation of the above statement would give the previous statement. **My understanding is stuck in the fact that **$$\begin{align}&\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\text{ are linearly dependent}\\\impliedby&\overrightarrow{d}\text{ cannot be expressed in any linear combination of }\overrightarrow{a}\text{, }\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and }\overrightarrow{c}\end{align}$$
$\det{A}=0\impliedby\text{no solution}$ is the reason why the above statement is true. **I lack the intuition that it is true. Could anyone fill me in with the "vector view" of such statement?**

Thank you.

Comment: $+1$, very nice post! However, the part where you mention "**My goal is to understand...**" is actually incorrect. It should be $\det(A)$ istead of $\det(A^{-1})$. If $\det(A) = 0$, then $A^{-1}$ doesn't even exist. (It's like dividing by $0$.)

Comment: The "geometric" meaning of the determinant is the "volume of the parallelepiped spanned by its column vectors", which is $a,b,c$ here. If $\det(A) = 0$, that means that the volume of this parallelepiped is $0$, so it's entirely flat if $\text{rank}(A) = 2$, a line if $\text{rank}(A) = 1$, and a point if $\text{rank}(A) = 0$. See this image for an example: https://mathinsight.org/image/volume_parallelepiped#:~:text=The%20volume%20of%20the%20parallelepiped,is%20perpendicular%20to%20the%20base.

Comment: I did not quite understand the question Do you want to try the following? Given any $D$ a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. If $D$ is written as a linear combination of $a, b$ and $c$ in $\mathbb R^3$, then $a, b$ and $c$ are linearly independent?

Comment: If the determinant is 0, then the matrix "flattens" some vectors it acts on. This destroys information, hence there cannot be an inverse matrix.

Comment: @Zaragosa I do find the negation very confusing. Correct me if I'm wrong, I think it is that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are linearly independent only if $D$ is written as unique linear combination of $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$? I wish I could write my statement in a more simple way but I don't know how ;(

Comment: @DanielP I believe $\rank{}$ is something from Linear Algebra, which I'll learn after Multivariable Calculus. From the contexts I've seen it before, I believe it describes the geometric relationships between planes defined by each linear equation in the system. It definitely have direct implications about the graphs of the planes and their intersections. I still have a hard time understanding how it relates to the "vector view" / linear combination of $\overrightarrow{d}$. Still, thank you so much for your answer :>)

Comment: The $\text{rank}(A)$ is the "dimension of the space spanned by the columns of $A$". I suggest reading the first little bit of linear algebra, up to and including the definition of a vector space, definition of the matrix rank, definition of the determinant, and maybe even solution to a system of linear equations using Gaussian elimination. I can guarantee it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to try: Let $a,bc\in\mathbb R^3$ nonzero vectors.

If for some $x\in\mathbb R^3$ non exists $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R$ such that $x=\alpha\cdot a+\beta\cdot b+\gamma\cdot c$. Then $a,b$ and $c$ are linearly dependent vectors.

or equivalently, we have:

If $a,b$ and $c$ are linearly independent vector. Then for all $x\in\mathbb R^3$ exists $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R$ such that $x=\alpha\cdot a+\beta\cdot b+\gamma\cdot c$.

**Here is a solution with vector spaces**

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are linearly independent vector. Let $Span\{a,b,c\}=$set of all linear combinations of the vectors a, b, and c. Then $\dim(Span\{a,b,c\})=3$ and $\dim\mathbb R^3=3$. Hence $\mathbb R^3=Span\{a,b,c\}$. And therefore let be any vector $x\in\mathbb R^3=Span\{a,b,c\}$, i.e. $x$ is linear combinations of the vector $a,b$ and $c$.

I am making use of the following result: Let $F$ be a vector subspace of an n-dimensional vector space $E$. If $\dim F=n$ then $F=E$.

**Here you have a solution with matrices**

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are linearly independent vector. Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3
\end{pmatrix}$ with $\det(M)\neq 0$. We want to solve the following system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\gamma
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\gamma
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It is so that it has a unique solution. That is for all $x\in\mathbb R^3$ exists $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R$ such that $x=\alpha\cdot a+\beta\cdot b+\gamma\cdot c$.

I hope I have understood your question well.